# CruiseControl.net Project Fails with no errors, how to identify error?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Had cruise control.net (v1.8.5.0) up and running for about 6 months on 4 projects, no issues.

In the past week or so, one project reports a failure... even though it compiles correctly and no unit test errors are reported as they were previously on failures.  None of similiar reports on SO or elsewhere describe or correct this problem.

Here is dashboard status:

> BluePrint Failure Breakers : support2 Failing Tasks : NUnitTask

In the build report log where it would normally show which tests failed, it shows no failures just the unit startup message:

> ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single Execution
>   Runtime: net-3.5

Normally here for an nunit error the erroring test #s and names that failed and the nunit assert failure message.  In a passing situation it would display xml for each test.

Can someone point me somewhere else what might be causing this or where else I might look to find out why?

When I run nunit manually on the same tests the cruise control service has checked out the build server, everything works fine.

I've tried restarting both the cruise control service and IIS, same result.

When I look in the ccnet.log file on the server, it doesn't report anything more specific than whats already in the build log above:

> Done Building Project
>   "C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\BluePrint.sln" (Build
>   target(s)).
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:13.99
>
> 2017-01-20 18:50:36,869 [BluePrint:DEBUG] Running unit tests:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe
>   /xml=C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\logs\LatestTests.BluePrint.xml
>   /nologo
>   C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\Tests\bin\x64\Release\TestBluePrint.exe
>   2017-01-20 18:50:36,869 [BluePrint:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe] in working directory
>   [C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\BluePrint\WorkingDirectory] with
>   arguments
>   [/xml=C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\logs\LatestTests.BluePrint.xml
>   /nologo
>   C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\Tests\bin\x64\Release\TestBluePrint.exe]
>   2017-01-20 18:50:36,953 [BluePrint:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on
>   [C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe] to default
>   Normal 2017-01-20 18:50:37,686 [20:DEBUG] [BluePrint C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe] ProcessModel: Default
>   DomainUsage: Single 2017-01-20 18:50:37,686 [20:DEBUG] [BluePrint
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe] Execution
>   Runtime: net-3.5

My configuration has not changed in 6months, here's the relevant task from ccnet.config:

```
      <nunit>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe</path>
    <outputfile>C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\logs\LatestTests.BluePrint.xml</outputfile>
    <assemblies>
      <assembly>C:\Users\j\Documents\CIWork\BluePrint\Tests\bin\x64\Release\TestBluePrint.exe</assembly>
    </assemblies>
  </nunit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was posting this I recalled that one of these tests downloaded a fair amount of data from internet and cached it.   Running it from the console worked, but running it from system account as service must've been slower to exceeded default cruisecontrol timeout.

Weird that no timeout error was in the log.  However copying the cached files from the admin account to systemprofile account fixed it.   Will also see if the nunit test can be modified to automatically time itself out.